# перебор файлов в папке c#

Tags: c#

Перебираю файлы в папке

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(fullPath);
foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles()) { 
    Console.WriteLine(file.Name);
 }
```

не понимаю почему файлы перебираются не в нужном порядке

```
2.txt
1.txt
4.txt
3.txt
```

файлы создавал в порядке 1-4.
ОС Ubuntu

Мне очень важен порядок файлов, на данный момент создаю коллекцию и сортирую, что бы обойти эту проблему.

Comment: Почему они должны перебираться в "нужном" порядке?

Comment: Порядок возвращаемых имен файлов не гарантируется; Используйте метод Sort, если требуется конкретный порядок сортировки.

Comment: под "нужным" порядком я понимаю что файлы изначально должны считываться в "алфавитном" порядке. Но почему это не так?

Comment: потому, что так написано в документации, [`Порядок возвращаемых имен файлов не гарантируется; Используйте метод Sort, если требуется конкретный порядок сортировки.`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.8). И это понятно, у файлов, кроме имени, есть ещё куча других аттрибутов. Нет никаких причин сортировать по имени при получении списка файлов.

Comment: Спасибо. Буду внимательнее читать документацию